# Time to deliver a baby

Tags: fallout-shelter

So, I started playing Fallout Shelter again and can't remember exactly how much time it takes for a female dweller to deliver a baby. Does anyone know that? And is the time for it fixed or does it get affected by stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bethesda support officially states "after a few hours"

https://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/29971/~/why-won%E2%80%99t-my-pregnant-dwellers-give-birth-in-fallout-shelter%3F

Other sources state "3 hours".

https://www.androidauthority.com/fallout-shelter-tips-tricks-guide-970517/